# Is there any simple Java-based word sense disambiguation using WordNet?

Tags: java, api, word-sense-disambiguation

I am looking for java-based WSD using WordNet that return the appropriate sense of a word based on a context. Can you provide me with some?

Comment: Word sense disambiguation is _hard_.  Generic word sense disambiguation (i.e. not limited to a specific domain) is _particularly hard_.  In many cases humans can't agree on which is _the_ appropriate sense in a given context, or even if there is one... Searching for "java word sense disambiguation" will give you a number of possibilities to start from, but whatever you use you'll probably need to customize in some form or re-train on your own data to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Not that I know, but I think you can create one. Could be a good project.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was hoping to find ready java-based tool that handle this. Perl got plenty WSD tools. But my project is in Java :(

In the mean time I don't have plenty of time to create it, but maybe in future I will.

Answer (score 3):

I think [BabelNet](http://lcl.uniroma1.it/babelnet/) might be useful to you. It does word sense disambiguation based on data from WordNet and Wikipedia.

[This paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P12-3012) (pdf) explains how it works and shows an example of WSD using their API.